# How to add a team member to Apple Developer Program

Tags: ios

Apple has redesigned the member area of developer.apple.com. Before we were able to invite developers via the "People" button at the header navigation. But now it's gone and I don't understand where to add team members.

I have googled for this, but have found only examples how it worked before: 
[How to add a team member](http://getmobipromo.com/help/add-a-team-member-to-your-apple-developer-program/)

Do you know, how to add a team member to the Apple Developer Program?

**Update:**
It turned out my Safari browser didn't display the mentioned start page with that menu. After deleting obsolete cookies everything was fine without redirecting.

Comment: You can always contact to Apple for the same.

Answer (score 6):

If you registered your account as Individual Developer then People tab not visible!

Comment: link is not reachable

Answer (score 0):

In the people section, that you can reach from left menu, you have at the center a big blue button named "Invite People". I think that's the one you want.